# Не работает sendmail

Tags: email, macos, smtp, sendmail

Пробую отправлять письма на почтовый ящик с помощью команды:

```
echo "this is the body" | mail -s "this is the subject" "to@address"
```

Письмо не приходит на нужную почту ни в спам, ни в папку с входящими письмами. Пробовала вводить команду:

```
(echo >/dev/tcp/localhost/25) &>/dev/null && echo "TCP port 25 opened" || echo "TCP port 25 closed"
```

Результат был таким: "TCP port 25 closed".
Как я понимаю, нужно открыть порт, или какие-то ещё необходимы настройки? Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.

**P.S.:** просмотрела неотправленные письма, которые возвращаются на мою локальную машину и увидела там: **"550 Unroutable sender address"**. Видимо, надо явно указывать адрес отправителя, только какой? Такая проблема с mail.ru, с Яндексом такой проблемы нет.

Comment: какую версию какого дистрибутив какой операционной системы вы используете?

Comment: попробуй `echo "this is the body" | mail -v -s "this is the subject" "to@address"` + `nestat -ant | grep :25 | grep LISTEN`

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip, Результат такой: "You have new mail in /var/mail/usr_name".

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip, проследила, какое письмо возвращается по адресу /var/mail/usr_name - там пишут, что произошла ошибка 550: "550
    Unroutable sender address (in reply to MAIL FROM command)".